# Why onChange event is not working properly in a dropdown when taking values as props?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, onchange, react-props, react-typescript

I'm working on a React typescript project and need to create a dropdown with the necessary name and link to navigate as props, which will be displayed as menu items in my dropdown. But when I defined values in the same dropdown.tsx file, the onChange event worked properly. But when I  received values as props, the onChange event won't work.

Here is my DropdownComponent.tsx file

```
import * as React from 'react';

import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';
import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';
import { Box, Button, InputBase } from '@mui/material';

// React-Router Imports
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom/';


/* eslint-disable-next-line */
export interface DropdownComponentProps {
  dashboardnames: Array<{
    name: string,
    link: string
  }>,
  renderDashboard:()=>void
}


export function DropdownComponent(props: DropdownComponentProps) {

  const [configName, setConfigName] = React.useState<string>();


  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof configName>) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setConfigName(value);
  };



  return (
   <Box   sx={{ marginTop:-5}}>
    <Select
          sx={{width:190,height:36}}
          displayEmpty
          value={configName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput />}
          renderValue={(selected) => {
            if (!selected) {
              return <>Mushroom tunnel 1</>;
            }

            return selected;
          }}
         
          inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }}
        >
          <MenuItem disabled value="">
            Frequently visited
          </MenuItem>
          <div style={{marginLeft:'20px', display:'flex'}}> <InputBase placeholder='search'/>
          <div style={{marginLeft:'10px', marginRight:'10px'}}>
            <Button><SearchOutlinedIcon /></Button>
            </div>
          
          </div>
          
        
          {props.dashboardnames.map((page) => (
              <MenuItem
                component={RouterLink}
                to={page.link}
                key={page.name}
                onClick={props.renderDashboard}
              >
              {page.name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
        </Box>
  );
}

export default DropdownComponent;
```

What's the mistake I've made here? Can someone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check if props are being received?

Comment: yeah, props are recieving, and links also working